# Media Queries para monitor com retina

Tags: css, media-queries

Estou tentando fazer uso da media query para monitor com retina (macbook pro), mas não consigo fazer o código ser considerado pelo browser de jeito nenhum, tentei de várias formas, considerando o [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/).

A meta tag do `viewport` está assim:

```
meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"
```

Tentei assim:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
    only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
```

Tentei assim também:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
    only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
```

E várias outras formas expostas no [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/).

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Cara eu deixaria a meta tag bem simples `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` pois é o media query que vai tratar isso ao meu ver (a escala é 1 para 1 independente dos dpi acredito). E teste com regras mais simples tipo `@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi) { suas classes }` Eu coloqueo o vendor prefix **-webkit-** pois o Safari é webkit e acho que até o momento sa a Apple tem esse lance de retina no paines

Comment: @hugocsl, valeu cara, mas infelizmente não surtiu efeito. Alterei meta viewport conforme vc sugeriu e nada mudou, e tentei tb regras simples para @media, como por exemplo:`@media (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){...}  @media (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){...}`. Não entendo, achei vários, mas vários exemplos mesmo, e todos mostram mais ou menos a mesma coisa, mas nada de entrar na @media, olhei o CSS renderizado, e num entra nem ferrando no @media...rsrs Obrigado mesmo assim cara, tenho q entregar este projeto essa semana, preciso dar um jeito!

Comment: Cara infelizmente não tenho um monitor retina para fazer uns testes para te ajudar... nessa vou ficar te devendo então... Tenta pegar um código pronto para testar e ve se funciona. Verifica tb as configs do seu monitor se ele está mesmo no "modo retina" ou algo do tipo